# ExtJS Multiple fields in ComboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have a store with the following fields:

- personName
- primaryRole
- secondaryRole

I want to populate a combo-box so that I can choose from either their primary or secondary role.

The combobox code I currently have looks like this:

```
roleName: {
    editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        store: persons,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'primaryRole',
        valueField: 'primaryRole'
    }),
    displayName: 'Role'
}
```

Is it possible to populate a combobox from two store fields, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the `tpl` and `displayTpl` configs for the combobox to display the data however you want. Here's an example from the ExtJS 4 documentation:

```
// Template for the dropdown menu.
// Note the use of "x-boundlist-item" class,
// this is required to make the items selectable.
tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{abbr} - {name}</div>',
    '</tpl>'
),
// template for the content inside text field
displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '{abbr} - {name}',
    '</tpl>'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the displayed value in the field itself, use the [`displayTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-getRecordDisplayData) config (be careful though if you use multiselection). For the underlying `Ext.view.BoundList` (i.e. the list which is displayed when the combo is expanded), overwrite the [`getInnerTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-method-getInnerTpl) function (can be done using the combo's [`listConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig) configuration):

```
editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    store: persons,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'primaryRole',
    valueField: 'primaryRole',
    displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="primaryRole">{primaryRole}<tpl else>{secondaryRole}</tpl>',
        '</tpl>'
    ),
    listConfig: {
        getInnerTpl: function() {
            return '<tpl if="primaryRole">{primaryRole}<tpl else>{secondaryRole}</tpl>';
        }
    })
}
```